# World repeat problem in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

do you know any way to disable world repeating on Google Maps?
My map has untypical dimensions and this is the reason why world is repeated horizontally. I cannot set higher zoom level for the map because some of continents would be cut off.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an image mask ( or-map ) on it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Also if you place markers, they repeat horizontally as well. Is there a way to keep them from repeating?

Comment: @Jakobud: I read your answer and I'm wrong. I'm sorry but overlay the world isn't to right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Set the draggable to false and zoom the map as per your div size

For example

```
var myOptions = 
{
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.375278, 78.474444),
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    rotateControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ... fixed using the below responsive css .. credits to labnol.org

```
<style>
    .google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```